# How to rename MYSQL database in RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have searched enough to find steps to rename a Database name in RDS MySql and unable to find one. Can someone point to the place  that has database renaming instruction on an RDS instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mysqldump`. Backup then restore database.

```
mysqldump -h [aws-host] –u [UserName] –p[Password] –R [DB_Name] > [DB_Name].sql
mysqladmin -h [aws-host] –u [UserName] –p[Pasword] create [New_DB_Name]
mysql -h [aws-host] –u [UserName] –p[Password] [New_DB_Name] < [DB_Name].sql
mysqladmin -h [aws-host] -u [Username] –p[Password] drop [DB_Name]
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do this in mysql shell right? I can no way do the renaming in AWS console. right?

Comment: mysql does not have rename database support. but you can use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing different about RDS here; to "rename" a database, you create the new database and then rename each table into it:

```
CREATE DATABASE new_db;
RENAME TABLE old_db.table1 TO new_db.table1;
RENAME TABLE old_db.table2 TO new_db.table2;
```

You will have to also add any grants, views, stored procedures for the old database to the new database.